# node.js sqlite transaction isolation

Tags: node.js, sqlite, transactions

How do I ensure that SQLite doesn't interleave queries from multiple concurrent node.js/Express HTTP requests into a single transaction?

I would want DB queries from different requests to be executed in separate transactions, isolated from each other, allowing each to be committed or rolled back independently of each other.  Given node.js's single-thread (and single-DB-connection?) characteristics this seems particularly problematic.

I've been trawling through dozens of web pages and docs and haven't found any clear (to me) explanation of how (or whether) this scenario is handled.  For instance the description of db.serialize() only states that one query will be executed at a time - it says nothing about the separation of queries belonging to different transactions.

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the exact same issue. Here is how I solved it:

**Step 1**: Dnsure all database access is done via a set of library functions, where the database is passed in as the first input parameter.

**Step 2**: When you create the database object (using `new sqlite3.Database('path')`), wrap the object with some extra meta-information:

Here is how I wrapped mine:

```
var wrap = { db_obj : new sqlite3.Database('path'), locked : "UNLOCKED", work_queue : [] }
```

**Step 3**: Create a function that will be used to run db functions. If the database is locked, this function will defer their execution until later. I called mine "runAsync":

```
function runAsync( db, fn, callBack) {
    if (db.locked === "LOCKED" ) {
        db.work_queue.push( function() { runAsync( db, fn, callBack ); });
        return;
    }
    fn(db,callBack);
}
```

We can see that this function checks the state of the wrapped db object. If it is locked, we defer execution by storing the function in the "work queue" to be executed later (by doing `fn()`).

**Step 4**: Create a function that will be used to run db functions **exclusively**. If the database is locked, this function will defer execution until later, else it will lock the database, run its function and then unlock the database. I called mine: `runAsyncExclusive()`:

```
function runAsyncExclusive( db, fn, callBack ) {
    if(db.locked === "LOCKED") {
        db.work_queue.push( function() { runAsyncExclusive( db, fn, callBack) });
        return;
    }
    var exclusiveDb = {
        db_obj : db.db_obj,
        locked : "UNLOCKED",
        work_queue : []
    };
    db.locked = "LOCKED";
    fn(exclusiveDb, function(err,res) {
        db.locked = "UNLOCKED";
        var workItems = db.work_queue;
        _.each(workItems, function(fn) { fn(); });
        db.work_queue = [];
        callBack(err,res);
    })
}
```

The exclusiveDb object that is passed into the function will allow exclusive access to the db. This object can itself be locked, allowing for arbitrarily deep nested locking.

**Step 5**: Adjust your library functions such that they call `asyncRun()` and `asyncRunExclusive()` where appropriate:

```
function get(db,sql,params,callBack) {
    db.get(sql,params,callBack);
}
```

Becomes...

```
function get(db,sql,params,callBack) {
    runAsync( db, function(db,cb) { db.get(sql,params,cb); }, callBack );
}
```

Voila!

(Apologies if this wasn't clear enough)

Comment: That makes sense - thank you!  I take it that you use the pair of functions runAsync & runAsyncExclusive to implement patterns like multiple-readers-vs-single-writer?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be thread-safe. The read-write of db.locked is not done atomically. What if two threads call runAsyncExclusive virtually at the same time? You could end up with two threads reading db.locked === "UNLOCKED" and starting their business.

Comment: You're right in that its not thread-safe. This shouldn't be an issue though as node.js is single threaded right?